# Endomorphisms preserve Haar measure

Tags: topological-groups, ergodic-theory

I am having trouble following the argument in page 21 of P. Walters, Intro. to ergodic theory, of the following statement:

> Any continuous endomorphism on a compact group preserves Haar measure.

Obviously, this is not true as stated, as the trivial homomorphism does not preserve Haar measure. Even restricting ourselves to nontrivial homomorphisms, I am still unable to follow the argument, which is as follows:

Let $A : G \rightarrow G$ be the endomorphism and let $m$ denote the Haar measure. Define a probability measure on Borel sets $\mu(E) = m(A^{-1}(E))$ . Now,

$$ \mu(Ax.E) = m(A^{-1}(Ax.E)) = m(x.A^{-1}E) = \mu(E) .$$

I agree with the first equality by definition, and the last equality because of $m$ being a Haar measure. But I am unable to fathom why the middle equality is true.

Moreover, even if the said equality is true, the rest of the proof goes as follows: We see that $\mu$ is rotation invariant, and we use the uniqueness of Haar measure to prove that $\mu = m$. In this, I am unable to see how the above equality assures that $\mu$ is rotation-invariant.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This thread is relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/65565

Comment: So, the moral is that the proof given by Walters is nonsense, and I should rather follow kneidell's proof at the link given?

Comment: The version of Walter's book on Google books gives a different statement. There he writes "Any continuous endomorphism of a compact group *onto itself* preserves Haar measure."

Comment: @Byron : I didn't type the extra two words out of laziness. Isn't an endomorphism by definition a homomorphism to the same object?

Comment: @DoubtingThomas The key word is *onto*. This says that the image of the map is the whole space.

Comment: One moral I see here is this: when quoting from a source, make sure to get the quotation entirely correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The moral is that you have to assume surjectivity of $A$.

For the **middle equality**: we have $A^{-1}(Ax.E)=x.A^{-1}E$ as sets:

$y\in A^{-1}(Ax.E)$ means $Ay\in Ax.E$ means $A(x^{-1}y)\in E$, while

$y\in x.A^{-1}E$ means $x^{-1}y\in A^{-1}E$.

For the **rotation-invariance**: we now see $\mu(Ax.E)=\mu(E)$ for all $x\in G$. In other words, $\mu(y.E)=\mu(E)$ for all $y\in \text{im} A\subset G$. By *surjectivity* we have $\text{im} A=G$.

Comment: Thanks, I have got the equality part. But I still don't get the rotation invariance. Sorry. Could you please elaborate on that part?

Comment: @DoubtingThomas: I interpreted 'rotation-invariance' to be *defined* by $\mu(g.E)=\mu(E)$ for all $g\in G$ and Borel sets $E$. So this is just the invariance in the definition of Haar-measure.

Comment: Yes, what I didn't get was how you got $\mu(y.E) = \mu(E)$ from the equality and surjectivity.

Comment: @DoubtingThomas: I have edited my answer, please let me know if it is clear to you.

Comment: Ah, I see .. Thank you very much!